# How do I draw lines on a image using mouse clicks in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

So, after following the advise from the stackexchange users about mouse event, I was able to understand and implement some simple task using mouse clicks. So, the next goal was to draw a simple line using the mouse left click and mouse right click. Unfortunately, I can't see any line after I implemented my program.

```
int x,y;
Point p(0,0);
Point q(0,0);

Mat xal;

void drawimage()
{
    a = q.x - p.x; //i am just checking out the values of a and b to see if the     drawimagefunction is being called in the rightmouse click event
              b = q.y - p.y;
              cout<<" a is :"<<a<<endl;
              cout<<"b is:"<<b<<endl;
    line(xal,Point(p.x,p.y),Point(q.x,q.y),Scalar(0,0,255),2,8);
}

void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int f, void* )
{
    switch (event)
    {
        case EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:


            cout<<"Left button was pressed"<<x<<" "<<y<<" "<<endl;

            {
                p.x = x;
                p.y = y;
                cout<<"p is:"<<p.x<<p.y<<endl;
            }
            break;

        case EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
            cout<<"Right button was pressed at :"<<x <<" "<<y<<endl;


            {
                q.x = x;
                q.y = y;
                drawimage();//no line is being drawn though i can see that i get the values of a and b in the drawimage function.
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
int main()
{
    xal = imread("pic.JPG);
    namedWindow("Picture",1);
    setMouseCallback("Picture",onMouse,NULL);
    imshow("Picture",xal);
    cvwaitkey(0);
}
```

Comment: Haven't looked too hard yet (on mobile), but one error in your code is in your if statements, you are assigning clicked to true rather than testing against it.

Comment: you will have to *reset* clicked at the end of the EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN statement (else, it's always on)

Comment: @berak: - i changed it to Case event_rbuttondown: clicked = false; if(clicked = false) { ---------------------same as above} nothing happens though.

Comment: *after* evaluating clicked, not before

Comment: Hi Rebecca, you need to use "==" within if statements, like: if (clicked == true) {...}. Otherwise, you are making clicked true in the if statement, rather than checking if it is true.

Comment: @adairdavid: thanks for the correction. I really appreciate it. But even after eliminating the bool clicked from the if statements, i tried executing the program but for some reason i am not able to draw. Ironically, just before calling the drawimage() function in my rightbuttonevent, i tried calculating the distance between q.x-p.x = a ; q.y - p.y =b and it gave me correct results of a and b. But the drawimage function doesnt execute. Any idea?

Comment: Please edit your original post with your updated code, that way we can always be sure we are on the same page when giving advice. Add an output to the drawLines function so you can see if it is being called.

Comment: @adairdavid:- awesome idea david.Let me update it right now.

Comment: @adairdavid:- david i updated the code. Though i can see that the drawimage function is being called as i get the values of a and b when i click on the right mouse click. The only thing is that i cant draw any line.

Comment: Try adding another imshow(..) after the line(..) call, may just need to refresh the image shown on the screen. The same imshow(..) you have in main(..).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following after your "line(..)" call in your drawLine() function:

```
imshow("Picture", xal);
```

The problem is that you are writing the line to the xal matrix, but you have not updated the image on the screen, which is what the imshow(..) call will do.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one code. It is useful for you.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void drawimage()
{
    line(xal,Point(p->x,p->y),Point(q->x,q->y),Scalar(0,0,255),2,8);
}

void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *ptr )
{
    if ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
    {
        Point*p = (Point*)ptr;
        p->x = x;
        p->y = y;
        drawimage();
    }
    else if  ( event == EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN )
    {
        Point*q = (Point*)ptr;
        q->x = x;
        q->y = y;
        drawimage();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Read image from file 
    Point p;
    Point q;
    Mat xal = imread("MyPic.JPG");

    //if fail to read the image
    if ( xal.empty() ) 
    { 
        cout << "Error loading the image" << endl;
        return -1; 
    }

    //Create a window
    namedWindow("My Window", 1);

    //set the callback function for any mouse event
    setMouseCallback("My Window", CallBackFunc,&p);
    setMouseCallback("My Window", CallBackFunc,&q);

    //show the image
    imshow("My Window", xal);

    // Wait until user press some key
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: :- nothing happens. I still cant draw any line.

Comment: :- let me try it out.

Comment: :- sorry but nothing happens. I cant draw any lines.

Comment: You need to do your homework and learn about object lifetimes and scopes. This code does not even compile.